# Which is the better option to get an sub-array with specific keys and values from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have encountered this case many times in my work, need to get an sub-array with specific keys from an array. Today I want to make it a better performance, So my question is which is the better option:

**Sample Option 1:**

```
$where_requires = array('group_id', 'name');
$item = array('group_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Bob', 'age' => 37);

$where = array_diff_key($item, array_diff_key($item, array_fill_keys($where_requires, '')));
```

**Sample Option 2**

```
$where = array();
foreach($where_requires as $require){
    $where[$require] = $item[$require];
}
```

Remeber that both $where and $where_require is a big array, about hundreds elements. The timing cost at my machine make no obvious difference, Could you give me some advice? Better explainning why. Thanks all who notice my question.

Comment: Could you post a result you need to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
$where = array_intersect_key($item, array_flip($where_requires));
```

Comment: Good one Bro, shame on me didn't notice the 2 built-in function, haha.